# Looping through csv files and outputting calculations to one consolidated csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, csv, pandas

I am trying to loop through a specified folder, containing a bunch of .csv files. The purpose is to gather three metrics listed in each file, add them up, and output that to a row in a consolidated, soon-to-be-produced-by-python csv file.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

results_output = pd.DataFrame(index = None, columns=["gross_revenue","impressions","bid_requests"])
filenames = os.listdir("Z:/some/folder/path")

count = 0

for file in filenames:
    file_path = "Z:/some/folder/path/" + file
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path,skiprows=[0])
    data.columns = ["product1_gross_revenue","product2_gross_revenue","product3_gross_revenue"]
    gross_revenue = (data.product1_gross_revenue[0] + data.product2_gross_revenue[0] + data.product3_gross_revenue[0])
    if gross_revenue > 0:
        count += 1
        results_output.gross_revenue[1+count] = [gross_revenue]
        results_output.to_csv("data.csv",index=False,header=False)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    results_output.gross_revenue[1+count] = [gross_revenue]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-win3
, in __setitem__
    values[key] = value
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I can print out all the revenue items on the console so I know it is calculating correctly through each file, and a "data.csv" file is generated, but it remains at 0kb, with nothing ever being written to it, so I suspect this is where I am making a mistake.

This is what I want my "data.csv" file to look like:

```
0 gross_revenue[file1]
1 gross_revenue[file2]
2 gross_revenue[file3]
3 gross_revenue[file4]
4 gross_revenue[file5]
5 gross_revenue[file6]
6 gross_revenue[file7]
```

Hopefully I have supplied all useful bits of information, happy to provide anything else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean to increment count and then use (1+count) for the index of results_output.gross_revenue? ie..you are in essence incrementing twice (only one increment is permanent )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `results_output` dataframe, you are creating it with zero elements in the index. That's why (I think) it throws you an error when you try to access it.
Try creating it with an index equal to the number of files.
I also changed the way you used `count` 'cause I think it was off by 2.
I haven't tested the code below, but give it a try and report back if you find an issue

```
import pandas as pd
import os

filenames = os.listdir("Z:/some/folder/path")
n_files = len(filenames)
results_output = pd.DataFrame(index = range(n_files), columns=["gross_revenue","impressions","bid_requests"])

count = 0

for file in filenames:
    file_path = "Z:/some/folder/path/" + file
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path,skiprows=[0])
    data.columns = ["product1_gross_revenue","product2_gross_revenue","product3_gross_revenue"]
    gross_revenue = (data.product1_gross_revenue[0] + data.product2_gross_revenue[0] + data.product3_gross_revenue[0])
    if gross_revenue > 0:
        results_output.gross_revenue[count] = [gross_revenue]
        results_output.to_csv("data.csv",index=False,header=False)
        count += 1
```

(Slightly more pythonic, if you wanna keep the order of files: drop the `count` variable outside and do `for count, file in enumerate(filenames)` )

Comment: Thanks cd98, I deleted my previous comment; I made a typo (rookie mistake for a rookie), causing an IndexError - this worked thought, thank you!